# Flag history on first flag

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, reportes

Yesterday I raised my first flag on this site (not the meta) and I'm unable to see the `helpful flags` link on my profile. If I use the [direct link](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/2005) then I can see the flag is not approved yet.

I think the `helpful flags` line should appear in the profile once the first flag is raised (with a 0, for example), so you can see the state of your  first flag.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 'helpful flags' link is hidden until the flag count is above 0. You should see that now, as your flag has now been "found helpful."

Showing the link even when the count is 0 (at least when there are pending flags) probably makes sense, and should be requested on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), as that will get more attention from the software developers.  It likely has already been asked there, although a quick search didn't find anything for me.